# MARS Backup (system state) backup failing - Windows server 2012

Tags: azure-backup-vault

MARS Backup - system state backup failing
I am having issues with few servers, where the system state is not getting backup.

[MARS system backup failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb8A3.png)

I did follow the article below and attempt it, by changing the scratch folder to different location, it did not made any difference.

How do I change the cache location for the MARS agent?
Run this command in an elevated command prompt to stop the Backup engine:
Net stop obengine
If you have configured System State backup, open Disk Management and unmount the disk(s) with names in the format "CBSSBVol_".
By default, the scratch folder is located at \Program Files\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Scratch
Copy the entire \Scratch folder to a different drive that has sufficient space. Ensure the contents are copied, not moved.
Update the following registry entries with the path of the newly moved scratch folder.
Table 2Registry path Registry Key Value
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Backup\Config
ScratchLocation
New scratch folder location
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Backup\Config\CloudBackupProvider
ScratchLocation
New scratch folder location
Restart the Backup engine at an elevated command prompt:
command Copy

Net stop obengine

Net start obengine
Run an on-demand backup. After the backup finishes successfully using the new location, you can remove the original cache folder.

Can I please have some advice, as I have got few servers where the system state is not being backed up.

Comment: any advice, please, I really need assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a failure in the Windows Server Backup operation. See this KB article for steps on how you can modify required registry keys to fix the Windows Server Backup failures.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4053355/microsoft-azure-recovery-services-agent-system-state-backup-failure